# Resolution of the Identity and Complex Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory, complex-integration

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T : H \rightarrow H$ be a self-adjoint operator.

Let $\sigma(T)$ be the spectrum of $T$, $\Sigma$ be the Borel sigma algebra of $\sigma(T)$ and $E$ be a resolution of the identity on $\Sigma$ (for $T$).

Suppose that $f$ is a bounded Borel function on $\sigma(T)$ and $A$ is a Borel set of $\sigma(T)$.

Consider the operator $S : H \rightarrow H$ defined by 
$$
\langle Sx, y \rangle = \int_A f(\lambda)\, dE_{x,y}.
$$

*I claim that $|\langle Sx, y \rangle| \leq \|f \|_{\infty} \|E(A)x\| \|E(A)y\|$, where $\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup \{ |f(\lambda)|: \lambda \in \sigma(T) \}$.*

It is easy to see that

$$
\left|\int_A f(\lambda) \, dE_{x,y} \right| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} |E_{x,y}| (A).
$$

But, how can I show that $|E_{x,y}|(A) \leq  \|E(A)x\| \|E(A)y\|$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n$ be disjoint subsets of $A$ with $\cup_{i=1}^n \omega_i = A$.

Note that

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n |E_{x,y}(\omega_i)| = \sum_{i=1}^n |\langle E(\omega_i)x,y\rangle| &= \sum_{i=1}^n |\langle E(\omega_i)x,E(\omega_i)y\rangle| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|E(\omega_i) x\| \|E(\omega_i)y\|\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \|E(\omega_i)x\|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \|E(\omega_i)y\|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&=\left(\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n E(\omega_i)x \right\|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n E(\omega_i)y \right\|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&=\|E(A)x\| \|E(A)y\|. 
\end{align}

This implies that $|E_{x,y}|(A)  \leq \|E(A)x\| \|E(A) y\|$.